# Highcharts: Can sunburst chart show percentage share to depict part-to-whole relationship like pie charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, sunburst-diagram

Percentage share is used to depict the part-to-whole relationship in a chart.

Observe the **point.percentage** property used in Pie chart series data labels to show the percentage share with respect to the whole chart :
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/

```
 plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to achieve the following:
[image: Sunburst chart with percentage share]

Reference of this example : https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/sunburst-chart-roadmap-what-would-you-like-to-see

I know that the above percentage share with respect to parent and with respect to whole chart, can be achieved by manually setting the respective values. But that involves manual calculations.

I want to know if Highcharts supports point.percentage for Sunburst charts. Its not given in the API reference and I also did not get it on debugging an example in JS Fiddle.Is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

No, `point.percentage` is only for stacked series or pies: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#.percentage

However, if you use a `dataLabels.formatter`, it's easy to calculate the percentage for each slice. In the formatter function, you'll have access to the current slice (`point`) and all the rest of the chart data:

**Example** (change `series.custom.percentage` to select percentage calculation)

```js
series: [{
    type: 'sunburst',
    data: ...,

    //https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.custom
    custom: {
        percentage: 'whole',  //'whole' or 'parent'
    },
    dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
            const point = this.point,
                  series = this.series,
                  mode = series.options.custom && series.options.custom.percentage;

            const chartTotal = series.__myTotal || (series.__myTotal = series.data.map(p => p.options.value || 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b));

            let percentage;
            switch(mode) {
                case 'whole':
                    percentage = point.value/chartTotal;
                    break;
                case 'parent':
                    const group = point.parent && series.chart.get(point.parent),
                          total = group ? group.value : chartTotal;
                    percentage = point.value/total;
                    break;
            }

            const val = (percentage === undefined) ? point.value : (percentage * 100).toFixed(1) + '%';
            return point.name + '<br>' + val;
        },
    },

    ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pntjgqby/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The JS Fiddle example is helpful.

Comment: Good to hear! If this solves your problem, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Consider doing that for the other questions you have asked here on SO as well.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: What if I wanted percentage share w.r.t whole chart?